# in google analytics, what is 'ga:accountName' for?

Tags: language-agnostic, google-analytics

In google analytics, what is 'ga:accountName' for ?

it might seem like a straightforward question but I can't find anywhere some documentation which tells me what ga:accountName is supposed to return.

if I run the google's code from the java example:

`private static void getAccountFeed(AnalyticsService analyticsService) 
      throws IOException, MalformedURLException, ServiceException {`

```
// Construct query from a string. 
URL queryUrl = new URL( 
    "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts/default?max-results=10"); 

// Make request to the API. 
AccountFeed accountFeed = analyticsService.getFeed(queryUrl, AccountFeed.class); 

// Output the data to the screen. 
System.out.println("-------- Account Feed Results --------"); 
for (AccountEntry entry : accountFeed.getEntries()) { 
  System.out.println( 
    "\nAccount Name  = " + entry.getProperty("ga:accountName") + 
    "\nProfile Name  = " + entry.getTitle().getPlainText() + 
    "\nProfile Id    = " + entry.getProperty("ga:profileId") + 
    "\nTable Id      = " + entry.getTableId().getValue()); 
}
```

}

it does return my website.

can anybody help ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's in this page [this page](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceAccountFeed.html) - the GA profiles are grouped into an account corresponding to the first part of the UA code (if you've only got access to one GA account you never really see it, but if your Google ID is linked to more than one GA account then there's a select-your-account intermediate page before you can choose the profile to report on).

> - dxp:property name=ga:webPropertyId—The
>     web property ID associated with the
>     profile.
> - dxp:property
>     name=ga:accountName—The name of the
>     account associated with the profile.
> - dxp:property name=ga:accountId—The
>     account ID associated with the
>     profile, used in the tracking code for
>     your web property (e.g. UA-**30481**-22).

(shamelessly cut&paste from link above)

Answer (score 0):

'ga:accountName' is Google Analytic Account Name.If you have Analytics account in the google. Go to google anlytics it will show you accountName along with id,PropertyName along with id , Profile Name along with id .The profile id need to get the Gadata